# Create dynamically named class within module namespace

Tags: ruby, ruby-grape

I'm working with a Grape API and I have models which have a url attribute that I'm using to dynamically mount endpoints for.  I need to be able to version them and I'm having trouble getting them to be properly namespaced when they're generated.

If I create a class within a module, that class is namespaced.

```
module MyModule
  module SubModule
    class MyClass
    end
  end
end
=> nil 
MyModule::SubModule::MyClass
=> MyModule::SubModule::MyClass
```

However, if I dynamically, create the class within a module, it isn't namespaced.

```
module MyModule
  module SubModule
    dynamic_name = "ClassName"
    Object.const_set(dynamic_name, Class.new)
  end
end
=> ClassName 
MyModule::SubModule::ClassName
NameError: uninitialized constant MyModule::SubModule::ClassName
ClassName
=> ClassName
```

Is there a way to namespace a dynamically created class?

Comment: you can just do `const_set`, no need for `Object.`

Comment: Well, you *explicitly* tell Ruby to set the constant in `Object`, what did you expect? You can *explicitly* tell Ruby to set the constant somewhere else in *exactly the same way*.

Comment: Thanks Max!  Jorg, you're right, but in this case Max hit the nail on the head.  I should've set it in the current scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object.const_set` explicitly sets the constant in the Object namespace, which is the root namespace. If you use `const_set` without `Object`, it will set the constant in whatever the current namespace is, which is `MyModule::SubModule` in your example.